# Using a string of characters in front of a variable name to inform information in a new column

Tags: r

So, I have a dataset that looks like this:

| R_fighter | B_fighter | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | Bob Down | Bob Down |
| Oliver Black | Harry Long | Oliver Black |
| Amy Kurev | Maria Brooke | Maria Brooke |

I want to add a column that adds a factor variable of `Red` or `Blue` called `"Winner_Colour"`.

I'm looking for a way for the code to look at the first letter of `column 1` and `2`, then look at `Winner` and create a new column `"Winner_Colour"` that has `Red` if the winner belongs to `R_fighter` or `Blue` if the winner belongs to `B_fighter`
I have a feeling it might involve an `if-statement` and a ```mutate()`` function but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `ifelse` :

```
df$Winner_Colour <- ifelse(df$Winner == df$R_fighter, 'Red', 'Blue')
```

Comment: Huh, it was that easy? I thought about something like that but i wasn't aware of the ifelse() function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We could use a numeric index without using `ifelse`

```
df$Winner_Colour <- with(df, c("Blue", "Red")[1 + (Winner == R_fighter)])
```